# Regex to block certain special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently stuck at completing the following regex.

My Regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.][a-zA-Z0-9.+:_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]$
```

and the matching structure is  `Sample:Te.st4:Test.Sample`  each name is separated with `:`
But I want to allow the each name to have any special characters other than the following ones.

```
> # *
```

I don't know how to write that regex. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I think you'll have to describe your requirements more clearly. What is an "entity"? What are valid and invalid entities? How many of them can/must there be? Give some examples, both matching and not matching.

Comment: You need a different [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Corrected the statements. entity is just a name.

Comment: `[^>#*]` matches everything except `>` `#` or `*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex `"^[^>#*]+$"` will match any input apart from something containing `>`, `#` or `*`.

From your existing regex it looks like you don't want to allow `:` to be the first or last character, in which case the regex you want is this:

`"^[^:>#*]+|([^:>#*][^>#*]+[^:>#*])$"`